# What does it mean about userRecord[@"firstName"] = self.me.firstName;?

Tags: objective-c

I have some problem about objective-C syntax, please reference following the source code.

What does the `userRecord[@"firstName"] = self.me.firstName;` mean?

Is it `[userRecord setObject:self.me.firstName forKey:@"firstName"]`?

Thanks for helping.

```
void(^fetchedMyRecord)(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) = ^(CKRecord *userRecord, NSError *error) {
    LOG_ERROR(@"fetching my own record");
    self.myRecord = userRecord;
    userRecord[@"firstName"] = self.me.firstName;
    userRecord[@"lastName"] = self.me.lastName;
    [self.publicDB saveRecord:userRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error){
        LOG_ERROR(@"attaching my values");
        NSLog(@"Saved record ID %@", record.recordID);
    }];
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userRecord` is of type `NSMutableDictionary`, that means it is a **key/value-store**!

You can access the **values** by providing the appropriate **keys**.

In your case, `userRecord` contains **values** for **keys** `firstName` and `lastName`.

In Objective-C, you have two possibilities to access **values**, both are functionally equivalent:

1. using `objectForKey:` / `setObject:forKey:`
2. using *syntactic sugar*

In your case, you **set values** in `userRecord` using the second option with syntactic sugar, alternatively you could use:

`[userRecord setObject:self.me.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];`, this is equivalent to your line:
`userRecord[@"lastName"] = self.me.lastName;`

So, to answer your question, yes, `userRecord[@"firstName"] = self.me.firstName;` is the same as `[userRecord setObject:self.me.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];`.

Note that this only works for objects of type `NSMutableDictionary`, not for objects of type `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Your explanation "dict[@"key"] is the same as setObject:forKey:" is slightly wrong. The subscript operator expands to `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`. In NSMutableDictionary this method calls `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

**In the above code you are placing value in dictionary
assigning value to dictionary with key FirstName**

Answer (score 0):

> What does the userRecord[@"firstName"] = self.me.firstName; mean?
>
> Is it [userRecord setObject:self.me.firstName forKey:@"firstName"]?

Exactly.

Long story: Your line of code expands to ...

```
[userRecord setObject:[[self me] firstName] forKeyedSubscript:@"firstName"];
```

... where `self.me.firstName` corresponds to `[[self me] firstName]` (if the @properties `me` and `firstName` have default getter names.)

In an `NSMutableDictionary` the method `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` is equivalent to `setObject:forKey:`.